# Json in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

i am getting a problem  to get  json string creating in javascript,
in console log getting pure json string

like

```
[{"elementId":"selectProduct","elemnetValue":"Y"},{"elementId":"productId","elemnetValue":"415"}]
```

but when i am storing the output of the json in variable

it change like

```
[{\"elementId\":\"selectProduct\",\"elemnetValue\":\"Y\"},{\"elementId\":\"productId\",\"elemnetValue\":\"415
"}]
```

so it can't parse by

JSON.parse(jsonString);

Comment: can you add your code for this?

Comment: Have you tried? Did you get an actual error? How did you inspect the variable? Could it be that inspector that is displaying it incorrectly?

Comment: how are you storing it in variable why did it change its format

Comment: Errm are you sure its a string and not an object? If that first code snippet is exactly how it looks in the console then its a normal JS object and not JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JSON.stringify to get a "parseable" string..

like

```
var str = JSON.stringify([{"elementId":"selectProduct","elemnetValue":"Y"},{"elementId":"productId","elemnetValue":"415"}]);

var json = JSON.parse(str);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

i am done with following code :

```
var jsonString;
 $("#submit").click(function() {
 var _intrimForm={  
};
var json=[];
var len = document.getElementById("myForm").elements.length;
for(var i=0;i<len;i++){

            var _id =document.getElementById("myForm").elements[i].id;
            var value = document.getElementById("myForm").elements[i].value;
            _intrimForm={
                'elementId':_id,
                    'elemnetValue':value
            };
            json.push(_intrimForm);  
}
console.log(json); 
 jsonString = JSON.stringify(json);
console.log(jsonString); 
readJsonFormElement();
});

function readJsonFormElement()
 {
  var jsonInterim = new Array();

  jsonInterim=JSON.parse(jsonString);
  for(var i=0;i<jsonInterim.length;i++)
     {
        var eId=jsonInterim[i].elementId;
        var eValue=jsonInterim[i].elemnetValue;
    }
  }
```